# How to solve a second order non linear ode system with bvp4c?

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to solve a system of two second order non linear Odes and since it is a boundary valued problem I suppose I need to use the bvp4c function.
The system I'm talking about is the following:

f''(x) = F(f,f',x);
s''(x) = G(f, f',s,s',x)

with the conditions f(0) = pi, f(inf = 35) = s(inf = 35) = 0. The F and G functions are known and I assumed that 35 would be a decent replacement for infinity.
It is separable and I have already solved for f but I don't know how to solve it for s either.
The code that allegedly solves for f is the following:

```
options = bvpset('RelTol', 1e-5);

Xstart = 0.01;
Xend = 35;

solinit = bvpinit(linspace(Xstart, Xend, 1000), [0, 1]);

sol = bvp4c(@twoode, @twobc, solinit, options);

x = linspace(Xstart,Xend);
y = deval(sol,x);
figure(1)
plot(x,y(1,:))
figure(2)
plot(x,y(2,:))

function dydx = twoode(x,y)
dydx = [y(2); ((-1/(x^2 + 2+sin(y(1))^2))*(2*x*y(2) + sin(2*y(1))*y(2)^2 - 
2*sin(2*y(1)) - (sin(y(1)^2)*sin(2*y(1)))/x^2) )];
end

function res = twobc(ya,yb)
res = [ya(1) - pi
yb(2)];
end
```

So my question is how can I use the results I obtained for f in order to solve the equation for s? I have tried doing the same things I did for f but if I define a function for s that uses y(1,:) and y(2,:) it gives me an error message that says y is not defined.

Since I am quite new to solving dfferential equations with Matlab and to using Matlab in general I am probably making some trivial mistake but I have been looking for answers and couldn't find any. I hope someone with enough patience can help me.

Thanks in advance for any useful advice.

Comment: I'm not familiar with boundary value problems, but I've spend a lot of time with ODE solvers like `ode45` or `ode15s`. Even if I had two-step problem to solve, I was always trying to do it in one execution of solver. It's really hard to use data from one step to run another. The results you have with `f` are not continuous.

Comment: Thank you @Karl for the answer but I still don't get how I can solve for 's'. Also, yes I noticed something goes wrong for 'f' close to zero but I don't really know why. I'm interested in the asymptotic behavior at infinity anyway, this seems to agree with what I am expecting.

Comment: Can you treat `f` and `s` as one long ODE system? This is what I meant.

Comment: Yes I suppose I can. The problem is I don't really know how to work with these two functions together. What is the right code that allows me to include the other equation so to solve them at the same time?

Comment: What's the dependence between `f` and `s`? If I get it correct, `dydx` and `res` refer to `f` part? So where is `s`?

Comment: Yes the code above refers only to 'f'. For the 's' function the equation is the following: s'' = -s'*(2x + 4sin(2f)*sin(f)^2*f')/(x^2 + 2sin(f)^4) - But as I said I don't know how to use previous data to solve it.

Comment: But the output from first step is 2x100 vector. So you use only one value from it?

Comment: What do you mean? I have used nothing so far. The code refers only to 'f'. The output is a 2x100 array where y(1,:) = f and y(2,:) = f'